# Alternative name for dispersion or spread

Tags: terminology, dispersion

The determinant of the covariance matrix gives us the square of the volume of a hyperrectangle aligned with the distribution whose side lengths are determined by the variances of the distribution in the eigenspace.
In the univariate case this boils down to variance.

But what should we call such a measure? What does this measure mean?

On the one hand we could say it measures the spreadedness of the distribution, or simply its spread. Synonymical names used in literature are 'dispersion', 'variability' and 'scatter'.

My problem with these names is that they are too ambiguous.
'Spread' could also refer to uniformity.
I need to disambiguate between uniformity and some other concept for which I am trying to find the right word.

What word would be appropriate?

Comment: I am not clear that any other name is needed. If you want to talk about the determinant of a covariance matrix, that's its name. Without claiming to answer your question as you want it answered, I note only that "spreadedness" strikes this native English speaker as utterly unidiomatic; "spread" will do fine as an informal word (J.W. Tukey was very fond of it). Your list could be extended with "scale", introduced by R.A. Fisher.

Comment: I used the (wrong) word 'spreadedness' in order to distinguish it from other conjugations of the verb 'to spread'.
The word 'determinant' itself is uninformative as to what it is it measures in the case of the covariance matrix.
Scale sounds interesting. I will have a look at that.

Comment: 'Dichotomization' will have to do. Though it is very uncommon to use that word in statistics, I really need a word which is different from 'spread', the word which is usually used for the concept.

Comment: I don't see that dichotomization has anything to do with any aspect mentioned here. It refers to a dichotomy or distinction between two things or values. That's quite unrelated to a scalar reduction.

Comment: I agree with @NickCox. Personally, I think that the term is intentionally "ambiguous". If you want more precise descriptions of which way the data is spread, you have to go higher than the second (central) moment, i.e. variance towards skewness and kurtosis, etc. That's where you describe flatness/peaked-ness of the data.

Comment: +1. A brief but illuminating discussion is contained in Mosteller and Tukey, _Data analysis and regression_, Addison-Wesley 1977. who emphasise that there is a place for vague concepts, which can be made precise in several ways. This may sound vacuous or trivial, but it's the nub of the matter. For some purposes we really do need broad, general terms. Conversely, giving a word a precise definition (as with e.g. variance) means that we should be careful about not using such a term vaguely or broadly.

Comment: A dichotomy doesn't necessarily contain a binary distinction. It might also refer to a gradual contrast in a spectrum. @rocinante it's true that dichotomy sounds like the inverse measure of peakedness, but I am not looking for higher order moments. The use of dichotomy in the current context maybe doesn't make much sense. However, in the context of my thesis it does make sense and I felt obliged to tell what word I had chosen.

Comment: @NickCox I totally agree. What I need is a broad concept which isn't used in literature for a precise measure, but which is more specific than the concept of 'spread' which is even broader.

Comment: I'd consult dictionaries and colleagues on "dichotomy" or any variant that you want to adopt. I won't be reading your thesis but I still advise against using dichotomy to mean "gradual contrast in a spectrum". The roots of "dichotomy" are words for "two" and "cut", and that cuts hard.

Comment: Good point. I didn't think to look at the roots yet. And yes I am still in discussion with a professor on the word. Maybe 'diversity'? Though that has the same root 'di', it doesn't seem to be used in such a binary fashion.

Comment: @Angelorf Oh, I thought you were looking for more precise descriptors of spread, hence my suggestion to go to higher moments. If your focus is on variance decomposition alone, then that's a separate issue altogether.

Comment: "Diversity" is based on Latin, not Greek; the roots are different.

Comment: More importantly, "diversity" is already in some fields (e.g. ecology) a contested, problematic term. I still don't see that you need a new name at all....

Comment: The problem is that I already use the term 'spreading' as referring to either points that lie on an expanding hypersphere or points that lie within an expanding hypersphere. I would call both those things 'spread', but maybe you know of a better name for that concept, so that I can refer to what the determinant measures as 'spread', but change what I now call 'spread' to something new.